# RFC 2616 with Apache 2.4

Tags: http, reverse-proxy, etags, apache-2.4

I'm using Apache 2.4.3 as a reverse proxy due to it's advertised compliance with RFC 2616. My app uses headers like this to enable caching at the proxy:

```
Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=0
Expires: ... (+1 day)
X-Group: A
Vary: X-Group
ETag: W/"foo1"
```

After the first request warms the cache, if my app changes to respond with this:

```
Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=0
Expires: ... (+1 day)
X-Group: B
Vary: X-Group
ETag: W/"foo2"
```

The app will respond with 304 Not Modified if the If-None-Match header from Apache matches the origin-generated ETag. However, Apache then caches the second 200 response and *replaces* the "foo1" record with the new response instead of caching both of the responses with different ETags. Therefore, instead of `If-None-Match: W/"foo1", W/"foo2"` the next revalidate request is just `If-None-Match: W/"foo2"`. So the cache is constantly getting misses instead of always getting hits.

From the RFC 2616 section 12.1:

> However, an    origin server is not limited to these dimensions and
>   MAY vary the    response based on any aspect of the request, including
>   information    outside the request-header fields or within extension
>   header fields    not defined by this specification.

I've tried the following combinations for Vary:

```
Vary: X-Foo
Vary: *
Vary: User-Agent
```

I've also tried both strong and weak ETags and no matter what I cannot get Apache to cache the two responses simultaneously, it *always* saves over the previous one. If it can't save more than one variance of a page then ETag is useless, Last-Modified would be just as good.

From the Apache 2.4 docs:

> mod_cache implements an RFC 2616 compliant HTTP content caching filter, with support for the caching of content negotiated responses containing the Vary header.

Note that it says "responses" plural. Am I mis-interpreting the HTTP spec or does Apache 2.4 just not fully support ETags after-all?

Comment: Sounds like you need to go [here](http://httpd.apache.org/bug_report.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give a couple of examples like this:

```
Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=0
Expires: ... (+1 day)
X-Group: A
Vary: X-Group
ETag: W/"foo1"
```

I notice in particular the `Vary: X-Group` header. Is `X-Group` a request header or a response header?

As per [RFC 2616 section 14.44](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44), `Vary` should list any *request* headers that will result in a different content representation from an origin server. From your example, I suspect `X-Group` might be a response header, in which case mod_cache won't be storing multiple versions of the given resource.

One thing you could try would be to set `Vary: If-None-Match`, which would let mod_cache store a version of the resource for each ETag. Admittedly, I haven't tried this. Assuming it works, one downside is that the first request from any client would be a cache miss.

Comment: You're right, I was mixing up requests/responses.. Still I found that Vary had no effect and the cache apparently only stores the latest version for a given url.